# Проблема с z-index CSS

Tags: css

Есть прямоугольник:

```
<div class="i">Hi world!</div>
```

Его стили:

```
.i{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

И его оверлей:

```
.i::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: 0.5;       
}
```

Ожидалось, что `z-index: 1;` перекроет оверлей, и текст будет белым, но на деле так не происходит.
Почему, и как вылечить ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Псевдоэлемент находится внутри блока-прямоугольника, он всегда будет выше. Решение - обернуть текст в скажем `<p>` и задать ему `position:relative;` и `z-index` выше оверлея

```css
.i{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.i p {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.i::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="i"><p>Hi world!</p></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Именно то что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что родитель не может быть сверху дочернего элемента. `:before` - дочерний элемент для `div`.

Comment: Большое спасибо!